# Selenium - How do I check my element in xpath has a specific img src url?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is a little niche, but I want to click on a discord reaction with selenium (python), but only the reaction that has a specific img src.

I had it working where it would be clicking on reactions however it was clicking on every reaction not just the one I wanted.

I've tried to make it only click on the certain element using the aria-label, however this didn't work either.

```
if i.get_attribute('aria-label') == "️, press to react":
```

My function:

```
def Bot():
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div")
    for i in elements:
        if i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/img").get_attribute("src") == "https://discord.com/assets/e14bea9653868307f4d1e70fa17e2535.svg":
            i.click()
            continue
        else:
            break
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="️, press to react" aria-pressed="true" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <img src="/assets/e14bea9653868307f4d1e70fa17e2535.svg" alt="️" draggable="false" class="emoji">
   <div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 9px;">2</div></div>
```

I'm just not exactly sure how to go about this and "verify" that the element I'm clicking on has the specific img src I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Switch `continue` and `break`. Currently the loop will stop if the first element in the `elements` array does not match.

Comment: Where specifically does this appear in the UI?

Comment: @Jortega I switched them but still no results. I think something is wrong with the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/img").get_attribute("src")
```

this always finds the same element ,

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/img"
```

if you want to find the child of i you have to use:

```
i.find_element_by_xpath(".//img").get_attribute("src")
```

See the '.' infront , this will find all child of 'i' , else the xpath search starts always for '/' root

```
def Bot():
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div")
    for i in elements:
        if i.find_element_by_xpath(".//img").get_attribute("src") == "https://discord.com/assets/e14bea9653868307f4d1e70fa17e2535.svg":
            i.click()
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: This is along the lines I'm looking for, but it's throwing NoElementException errors. Is there a simpler way to use i as the element to check the /img child for?

Comment: @Rohan please add the html , is `//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/img` a child of `//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div` , are you able to find the element as `//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/img`

Comment: Yes, in my post I added the html that the xpath is going to. The div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" is the element it needs to click, but I need to verify the img part below it.

Comment: @Rohan what  "//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div" this finds from the html you have added ? the div that is after img tag ?

Comment: add full html try then only i can tell something

Comment: "//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qnXI6')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div" finds <div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="️, press to react" aria-pressed="true" role="button" tabindex="0">

Comment: @Rohan updated the answer , you just have to give .//img , this will check for child img tag ( I believe only one img tag is there as child as per ypur html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead to click on an image with that tag.

```
tag='discord.com/assets/e14bea9653868307f4d1e70fa17e2535.svg'
try:
    i.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='{}']".format(tag))
    i.click()
    break
except:
    continue
```

Comment: Within my for loop? Just tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: I believe it won't work if it clicks the image, it needs to click the element in my **elements** variable.